# Extract Emails that Lying Between Special Characters Using Regex in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I extract only email from this certain pattern of string using regex in SQL?

**What I have :**
tb_1

| Logmessage |
| --- |
| Alan Robert <alan.robert@gmail.com> was assigned to <richard@yahoo.com> and <nelson@gmail.com> |
| Alan Robert <alan.robert@gmail.com> was unassigned to <khanjoyty@gmail.com> and <katy@gmail.com> |

**What I want:** tb_2

| email_1 | email_2 | email_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alan.robert@gmail.com | richard@yahoo.com | nelson@gmail.com |
| alan.robert@gmail.com | khanjoyty@gmail.com | katy@gmail.com |

I already have a solution for this but the tb_1 table has a huge amount of rows so my query output takes too much time. That's why I thought maybe **regex** would be more time-saving.

**My query:**

```
with cte as(
Select replace(replace(replace(replace(right(@logmessage, len(logmessage)-charindex('<', logmessage)+1), 
                                         Case when logmessage like '%unassigned%' Then ' was unassigned to ' 
                                       When logmessage like '%assigned%' then ' was assigned to ' End , '.'),' and ', '.'), 
                                                                        '<', '['  ),'>', ']') logmessage
From tb_1)

Select 
       PARSENAME(logmessage, 3) AS email_3,
       PARSENAME(logmessage, 3) AS email_2,
       PARSENAME(logmessage, 1) AS email_1
From cte
```

Comment: If the email addresses are always within `<>` characters, you could likely do something. Though honestly this is a task for something with much better string manipulation functionality; likely your ETL process that is taking the data from the source and putting it into your database.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have regex, hence why its best to do this sort of thing elsewhere.

Comment: @Larnu Can you please explain to me elaborately?

Comment: @DaleK thanks. Can you please tell me some other way.

Comment: Not really, @ShuchitaRahamn , I don't know what your ETL process is. You can't explain to someone how to use a vehicle if you don't know what vehicle it is; the same applies here.

Comment: Write it in your favourite code... then store the values normalised so you don't have this issue again.

Comment: @Larnu I am using Spoon for my ETL. I just need to get tb_1 data and push it to tb_2

Comment: I know nothing about spoon I am afraid.

Comment: My name isn't "Laura"...

Comment: But I never wrote Laura

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the use of a helper function

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8fa31cf23423a18be363c5f8c48329f0)**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (LogID int,[Logmessage] varchar(500))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Alan Robert <alan.robert@gmail.com> was assigned to <richard@yahoo.com> and <nelson@gmail.com>')
,(2,'Alan Robert <alan.robert@gmail.com> was unassigned to <khanjoyty@gmail.com> and <katy@gmail.com>')

Select A.LogID
      ,B.* 
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract-JSON](LogMessage,'<','>') B
```

**Results**

```
LogID   RetSeq  RetVal
1       1       alan.robert@gmail.com
1       2       richard@yahoo.com
1       3       nelson@gmail.com
2       1       alan.robert@gmail.com
2       2       khanjoyty@gmail.com
2       3       katy@gmail.com
```

It would then be a small matter to pivot the results

**The TVF if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract-JSON] (@String varchar(max),@Delim1 varchar(100),@Delim2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = [Key]+1
                  ,RetVal = trim(Value)
             From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(@String,'json'),@Delim1,'","')+'"]' )

          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1

)
```

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Thanks for the answer I actually learned a new technique from your query.